# Why doesn't Seq.groupBy work like I think it will with lists? (F#)

Tags: f#

Here's a sample code:

```
let x = [5, 6, 65, 2, 3];
let p = x.Head;
let y = Seq.groupBy (fun xx -> if xx < p then -1 elif xx > p then 1 else 0) x
printfn "%A" y
```

I expected it would output

```
[(0, [5]), (1, [6, 65]), (-1, [2, 3])]
```

But actually it outputs

```
seq [(0, seq [(5, 6, 65, 2, 3)])]
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your list is a list containing a single tuple:

```
let x = [5, 6, 65, 2, 3];
```

This is because commas define a tuple.  This is effectively the same as writing:

```
// Build a tuple
let temp = (5,6,65,2,3)
// Make a list where the single item is the tuple
let x = [temp]
```

You needed to use semi-colons to define the elements of a list:

```
let x = [5; 6; 65; 2; 3];
```

If you make that change, you'll see:

> `seq [(0, seq [5]); (1, seq [6; 65]); (-1, seq [2; 3])]`